# How does drawing view outside the screen affect performance in Android?

Tags: android, performance, webview

I am trying to create some kind of horizontal slideshow for multiple webviews. There can be a lot of views in the slider but only three at most will be displayed (one in the center, the other two partly hidden out of the screen).

In my early implementation, I create a custom viewgroup based on a `RelativeLayout`. I add all the webviews needed, and in the `onLayout` , I call the `layout` method of the three webviews that will be displayed. I switch the displayed webviews with scrolling.

So here is my question : what does Android does with the ones that are not been displayed ? Are their  `draw` method called ? Does having a lots of views not been displayed like that impact performance ?

And as a side-question, does the webviews load their content even if they are outside of the screen? Or do they need to be drawn ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the case you are describing, they will be drawn, even if not displayed.

The best thing for you to do in this case would be to use a ViewPager.

Viewpagers by default only draws the displayed content as well as the pages on the left/right of the content (this can be changed to draw them all if you want).

To answer your question:

Yes, the draw method is called. Its simply called off screen. The view fully exists and can be brought into view. This is why elements in scrollviews are always present.

This is why listviews/recyclerviews/viewpagers exist. Offscreen elements are handled by the parent viewgroup automatically to save memory.

Second question, yes, the webviews will load their content even when loaded outside the screen.